# Caribou opens even with the setting disabled

Tags: gnome, 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

I'm using a Dell Latitude E7470 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa and GNOME version 3.36.2.

My problem is that the on-screen keyboard opens up even if the setting is disabled. Pretty much the same thing as [bug #1723857](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1723857). I've tried downloading and enabling the [extension](https://github.com/keringar/cariboublocker), but that didn't work.

Does anyone have the same issue or any fix to this?